# How to call different functions on different int values in c

Tags: c, function

In an interview I was asked to write an efficient program such that for each integer value given, a function is called.

For example: if user enters 1 then `function one` will get executed if user enters 5 then `function five` gets executed and so on..

I was not able to come up with an efficient idea, like we can't use an if statement for checking the value entered and then executing the corresponding functions.

Is there any way we can do this in an efficient manner?

Comment: Using a `switch`-`case`? Or perhaps an array of function pointers? Also "efficient" in regards to what?

Comment: Are the numbers small? Could they be used as indexes into an array (of pointers to functions)? Or perhaps use hash-tables or trees or other similar solutions?

Comment: function pointers in an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the option would be using function pointers, as below.

> Declares a type of a void function

```
typedef void (*fp)();
```

> define your functions

```
void func1()
{}
.
.
.
void func10()
{}
```

> declare array of function pointers like below

```
fp function_pointers[10];  //declares the array
```

> Initialize the function pointers like below

```
 function_pointers[0] = func1()
  .
  .
  function_pointers[9] = func10()
```

> Call function using function pointers like below

```
 for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
 function_pointers[i]();
```

Comment: what if one has to do it in cpp ? the same method is followed or is there some other way of doing the same?

Answer (score 3):

Use function pointers.

***Simple example:***

```
#include <stdio.h>

//pointer to a void function declaration

typedef void(*someFunc)();

void f1() {
    printf("f1 function call\n");
}

void f2() {
    printf("f2 function call\n");
}

void f3() {
    printf("f3 function call\n");
}

//array of function pointers
const someFunc funcTable[] = {
    f1,
    f2,
    f3
};

int main() {
    uint number = 0;
    printf("Enter 0, 1 or 2\n");

    scanf("%u",&number);
    if(number < 3) {
        funcTable[number]();
    }
}
```